# C# Reading Dictionary<String, List<String>> using LINQ or foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have got a dictionary object as below:

```
private Dictionary<String, List<String>> errors =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I have implemented IDataErrorInfo inside my class Product .There is `Dictionary<String, List<String>> errors` in which are stored errors validating properties(Id,Name).If we look at dictionary as structure  then TKey will be string and it will contain PropertyName and TValue List of errors for that property.Here is a code:

```
public class Product : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int idValue;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return idValue; }
        set { if (IsIdValid(value) && idValue != value) idValue = value; }
    }

    private string nameValue;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return nameValue; }
        set { if (IsNameValid(value) && nameValue != value) nameValue = value; }
    }


    {
        bool isValid = true;

        if (value < 5)
        {
            AddError("Id", ID_ERROR, false);
            isValid = false;
        }
        else RemoveError("Id", ID_ERROR);

        if (value < 10) AddError("Id", ID_WARNING, true);
        else RemoveError("Id", ID_WARNING);

        return isValid;
    }


    public bool IsNameValid(string value)
    {
        bool isValid = true;

        if (value.Contains(" "))
        {
            AddError("Name", NAME_ERROR, false);
            isValid = false;
        }
        else RemoveError("Name", NAME_ERROR);

        if (value.Length > 5) AddError("Name", NAME_WARNING, true);
        else RemoveError("Name", NAME_WARNING);

        return isValid;
    }

    private Dictionary<String, List<String>> errors =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    private const string ID_ERROR = "Value cannot be less than 5.";
    private const string ID_WARNING = "Value should not be less than 10.";
    private const string NAME_ERROR = "Value must not contain any spaces.";
    private const string NAME_WARNING = "Value should be 5 characters or less.";


    public void AddError(string propertyName, string error, bool isWarning)
    {
        if (!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            errors[propertyName] = new List<string>();

        if (!errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            if (isWarning) errors[propertyName].Add(error);
            else errors[propertyName].Insert(0, error);
        }
    }


    public void RemoveError(string propertyName, string error)
    {
        if (errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) &&
            errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            errors[propertyName].Remove(error);
            if (errors[propertyName].Count == 0) errors.Remove(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return (!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? null :
                String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors[propertyName]));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make method inside my class in which I'm gonna read everything from Dictionary using foreach loops or even better LINQ .How can I do this ?

My idea,which is not working correctly

```
public void ReadAllErrors()
    {


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string propertyName in errors.Keys)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(propertyName + "\t");
            foreach (List<string> list in errors.Values)
            {
                foreach (string error in list)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(error.ToString() + "\n");
                }

            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: you want to iterate through the list of strings associated with the propertyName, not all values for every key

Comment: I want output like this : 
ID  
Value cannot be less than 5.

Name
Value should be 5 characters or less.

Comment: oh, you do? ... well then, ignore my solution below!

Comment: At least three people think you might be looping incorrectly! lol ... perhaps you should check out one of the three nearly identical solutions below and make sure you don't actually want something more like what they are returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by saying that this `Product : IDataErrorInfo` doesn't strike me as the most elegant architecture to accomplish what I think you are trying to accomplish. If anything, the error related methods and fields should be moved into a base class (not an interface), otherwise you will end up repeating all this logic in every single class.

But to answer your immediate question, you can fix your `ReadAllErrors()` function as follows:

```
public void ReadAllErrors()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string propertyName in errors.Keys)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(propertyName + "\t");
        foreach (string error in errors[propertyName])
        {
            sb.AppendLine(error.ToString() + "\n");
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

You could create something similar with LINQ like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", 
    errors.SelectMany(v => v.Value.Select(s => s)).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a compiler in front of me but I think you have just a minor logic error, try this:

```
public void ReadAllErrors()
{


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string propertyName in errors.Keys)
    {
      sb.AppendLine(propertyName + "\t");
      foreach (string error in errors[propertyName])
      {
        sb.AppendLine(error.ToString() + "\n");
      }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC it looks like you are iterating the list incorrectly. Will this work?:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (string propertyName in errors.Keys)
  {
    sb.AppendLine(propertyName + "\t");
      foreach (string error in errors[propertyName])
      {
        sb.AppendLine(error);
      }
  }
```

If not can you explain wht you are getting cf what you expect?

**EDIT:**
A linq query might be something like:

```
MessageBox.Show(errors.Select(e => e.Key + "\r\n" + e.Value.Select(v => v + "\r\n")))
```

I'd say the original was more readable.

You could probably inject the SB in there somewhere ...